как найти в таблице dataframe фрагмент текста и заменить его на другой текст?
Есть ДатаФрейм:
   BSS Reg  BS_number BS_name        BS_address     CELL
0  NaN  IR        129  IO029  Область Иркутская  IO0291
1  NaN  IR        129  IO029  Область Иркутская  IO0292
2  NaN  IR        129  IO029  Область Иркутская  IO0293
1  NaN  IR        192  IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1921
2  NaN  IR        192  IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1922

Как мне найти фрагменты текста которые начинаются на IO и заменить на IR? Получить пытаюсь такую таблицу:
   BSS Reg  BS_number BS_name        BS_address     CELL
0  NaN  IR        129  IR029  Область Иркутская  IR0291
1  NaN  IR        129  IR029  Область Иркутская  IR0292
2  NaN  IR        129  IR029  Область Иркутская  IR0293
1  NaN  IR        192  IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1921
2  NaN  IR        192  IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1922

желательно по условию, чтобы выводилась таблица такая если есть IO. Потому что IO может и не быть в таблице.
следующий код это мои попытки получить такую таблицу:
        '''if ces2gTable["Reg"] != ces2gTable["BS_name"].str[:2]:
            ces2gTable=ces2gTable.drop("BS_name", axis=1)
            print("TRUE")
            #ces2gTable["BS_name"] = ces2gTable["BS_name"].str.replace("IO", "IR") 
        else:
            print("FALSE")'''
        addcol=ces2gTable["BS_name"]
        ces2gTable.insert(6, "RegIO", addcol)
        ces2gTable["RegIO"] = ces2gTable["RegIO"].str[:2]
        if "IO" in ces2gTable["RegIO"]:
            print("TRUE")
        else:
            print("FALSE")
        print(ces2gTable)
        print(ces4gTable)


А чем вас не устроило str.replace закоментаренное? Можно просто делать его без всяких проверок, лишнего оно не сделает (где нечего менять, там не поменяет). Правда, оно будет менять не только на первой позиции, а везде, где найдёт

@CrazyElf, условие мне нужно для того чтобы вернуть в обратно потом в IO. иначе он пооментся для остальных названий с IR. пожэтому пытался создать RegIO

Что-то я совсем запутался, что же вы хотите сделать. Боюсь, автор ответа ниже тоже вас не совсем понял. Из примера данных кажется, что вы просто хотите поменять все IO на IR. Прежде всего - зачем вы это делаете, какую задачу вы решаете? Так то вы же всегда можете сделать копию датафрейма и работать с ней, или вы можете сделать копию колонки с другим названием, если вы не хотите утратить изначальные данные.

@CrazyElf Вы все верно поняли, я хочу поменть данные. но после того как проделаю операции, откатить назад

Выглядит очень странно, ну да ладно. Вы всегда можете просто сохранить куда-то содержимое колонки, а потом скопировать его обратно в колонку. Хоть в другую колонку того же датафрейма, хоть просто в переменную. Это одним присваиванием делается.

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''   BSS Reg  BS_number BS_name        BS_address     CELL
              NaN  IR        129  IO029  "Область Иркутская"  IO0291
              NaN  IR        129  IO029  "Область Иркутская"  IO0292
              NaN  IR        129  IO029  "Область Иркутская"  IO0293
              NaN  IR        130  " X"  "Область Иркутская"  IO0293
              NaN  IR        130  "" "Область Иркутская"  IO0293
              NaN  IR        192  IR192  "Область Иркутская"  IR1921
              NaN  IR        192  IR192  "Область Иркутская"  IR1922'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
print(df)

df[['BS_name','CELL']] = df[['BS_name','CELL']].replace('^IO', 'IR', regex=True)
print(df)


   BSS Reg  BS_number BS_name         BS_address    CELL
0  NaN  IR        129   IO029  Область Иркутская  IO0291
1  NaN  IR        129   IO029  Область Иркутская  IO0292
2  NaN  IR        129   IO029  Область Иркутская  IO0293
3  NaN  IR        130       X  Область Иркутская  IO0293
4  NaN  IR        130     NaN  Область Иркутская  IO0293
5  NaN  IR        192   IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1921
6  NaN  IR        192   IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1922
   BSS Reg  BS_number BS_name         BS_address    CELL
0  NaN  IR        129   IR029  Область Иркутская  IR0291
1  NaN  IR        129   IR029  Область Иркутская  IR0292
2  NaN  IR        129   IR029  Область Иркутская  IR0293
3  NaN  IR        130       X  Область Иркутская  IR0293
4  NaN  IR        130     NaN  Область Иркутская  IR0293
5  NaN  IR        192   IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1921
6  NaN  IR        192   IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1922



df['BS_name'] = df['BS_name'].str.replace('^IO', 'IR', regex=True)
df['CELL'] = df['CELL'].str.replace('^IO', 'IR', regex=True)
print(df)


   BSS Reg  BS_number BS_name         BS_address    CELL
0  NaN  IR        129   IO029  Область Иркутская  IO0291
1  NaN  IR        129   IO029  Область Иркутская  IO0292
2  NaN  IR        129   IO029  Область Иркутская  IO0293
3  NaN  IR        130       X  Область Иркутская  IO0293
4  NaN  IR        130     NaN  Область Иркутская  IO0293
5  NaN  IR        192   IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1921
6  NaN  IR        192   IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1922
   BSS Reg  BS_number BS_name         BS_address    CELL
0  NaN  IR        129   IR029  Область Иркутская  IR0291
1  NaN  IR        129   IR029  Область Иркутская  IR0292
2  NaN  IR        129   IR029  Область Иркутская  IR0293
3  NaN  IR        130       X  Область Иркутская  IR0293
4  NaN  IR        130     NaN  Область Иркутская  IR0293
5  NaN  IR        192   IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1921
6  NaN  IR        192   IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1922

Чтобы создать датафрейм, использую pandas.read_csv для считывания из файла или буфера, помещаю в буфер строку и считываю read_csv(StringIO(data))

delim_whitespace bool, по умолчанию False Указывает, будут ли
пробельные символы (например, ' ' или '\t') использоваться в качестве
разделителя sep. Эквивалентно установке sep='\s+'. Если этот параметр
установлен в True, то для параметра разделителя ничего не нужно
передавать.

Если нужно перенести данные в другую колонку можно это сделать так:
df['DopColumn'] = df['BS_name'].str.replace('^IO', 'IR', regex=True)


BSS Reg  BS_number BS_name         BS_address    CELL DopColumn
0  NaN  IR        129   IO029  Область Иркутская  IO0291     IR029
1  NaN  IR        129   IO029  Область Иркутская  IO0292     IR029
2  NaN  IR        129   IO029  Область Иркутская  IO0293     IR029
3  NaN  IR        130       X  Область Иркутская  IO0293         X
4  NaN  IR        130     NaN  Область Иркутская  IO0293       NaN
5  NaN  IR        192   IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1921     IR192
6  NaN  IR        192   IR192  Область Иркутская  IR1922     IR192


from io import StringIO этоаналог библиотек regex???

@DatoDato Да это просто для примера загрузки данных сделано, вам это не нужно будет.

@DatoDato добавил в ответ

@DatoDato Прочитал вашу переписку, добавил в ответ.
